# Imputation of one column with the median of the values of that column corresponding to another categorical column with their categories

Tags: r

I have a dataset combi, and I want to impute all the values of item_visibility columns that have zeros with the median of the item_visibility values corresponding outlet_size column which has three categories "high" "small" and "medium" respectively in R. I know that we should use the dplyr groupy and summarize function. I'm lost after that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your question as suggested for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data %>%
  group_by(outlet_size) %>%
  mutate(item_visibility = ifelse(0,median(item_visibility),item_visibility))
```